# Не могу подключить sass к React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, sass, scss

Всем привет! Не могу подключить Sass к React. Делаю все по видео-уроку.
Открываю консоль в папке с `app.css` и задаю команду `npm install node-sass --save`.
`React` у меня не самая последняя версия, но сервак открывает, все компилируется.
Вот какую ошибку выдает командная строка:

```
$ npm install node-sass
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

> node-sass@7.0.1 install C:\Верстка\Обучение JS\React\10й урок\my-app\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v7.0.1/win32-x64-79_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v7.0.1/win32-x64-79_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@7.0.1 postinstall C:\Верстка\Обучение JS\React\10й урок\my-app\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Верстка\Обучение JS\React\10й урок\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Верстка\\Обучение JS\\React\\10й урок\\my-app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
gyp info using node@13.14.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
gyp verb find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp verb find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp verb find Python - executing "python" to get executable path
gyp verb find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe
gyp verb find Python - executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" to get version
gyp verb find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp verb find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 3
gyp verb find Python - executing "py.exe" to get Python 3 executable path
gyp verb find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 3
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Верстка\Обучение JS\React\10й урок\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:330:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Верстка\Обучение JS\React\10й урок\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:159:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Верстка\Обучение JS\React\10й урок\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:228:18)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Верстка\Обучение JS\React\10й урок\my-app\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:294:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:310:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:322:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Верстка\\Обучение JS\\React\\10й урок\\my-app\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Верстка\Обучение JS\React\10й урок\my-app\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v13.14.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for npmlog@6.0.2: wanted: {"node":"^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=16.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.14.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npmlog@6.0.2
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for gauge@4.0.4: wanted: {"node":"^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=16.0.0"} (current: {"node":"13.14.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: gauge@4.0.4
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for are-we-there-yet@3.0.0: wanted: {"node":"^12.13.0 || ^14.15.0 || >=16"} (current: {"node":"13.14.0","npm":"6.14.4"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: are-we-there-yet@3.0.0
npm WARN fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@6.5.2 requires a peer of typescript@>= 2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.21.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@7.0.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@7.0.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-15T03_37_48_724Z-debug.log
```

Почему-то ругается на `Python`, но в уроке про него ни слова.
Кто знает в чем дело?

Comment: В npm node-sass написано, что он устарел. Вместо него устанавливайте просто sass. 
И ещё устанавливать лучше не в отдельной папке со стилями, а в корне проекта

Comment: Просто прописать npm sass? Или как?

Comment: npm i sass
можно ещё добавить --save-dev

Comment: установилось что-то, но ни одного файла я не нашел, куда смотреть можете подсказать?

Comment: Посмотрите package.json 
Если там есть модуль sass, то значит установился

Comment: установилось. порядок, спасибо!

Comment: В package.json модуль Sass есть, но как теперь сами файлы будут компилироваться в .scss?

Comment: Если вы разворачивали приложение с помощью create-react-app, то там уже всё за вас настроено. Просто меняйте расширение файлы на scss и пишите